# Category links not working after category filter is used in channel

Tags: categories

I have been trying to get the category links to filter properly on a news site.

Whenever I click on a category I'd like to filter, it still shows everything.

The filter worked before the restriction was implemented.

Below is the code (The area I need help with is where "entry-info" starts):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="11" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="both" category_group="1" category="33" show_empty="no"}
{exp:eehive_hacksaw words="110" allow="<a><p><i><h2><img>" append="&nbsp;<a href={url_title_path='news/entry'} <i>...Read more</i></a>"}
    <a href="{url_title_path='news/entry'}"><h2>{title}</h2>
    <img src="{img_news_tn}" id="ed-feat01-tn"></a>
    {if sub_headline}{sub_headline}{/if}

    {news_body}

{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
<p id="entry-info">Date Posted: {entry_date format='%M %j%S %Y'} | Posted in: {categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path='news/'}">{category_name}{/categories}</p>
```

Any help on this would be great. The site is set to go live next Friday and I'd like to fix this problem ASAP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: one question! If `category_group="1" category="33"` is hard coded, how the filter works?

Comment: Robson: I ended up deleting the category_group and category filter altogether. In the end, I just made a separate category group for the filtering instead.

Comment: If you find your solution, @wsvho, please, post your answer to help somebody else. Thanks!

Comment: @RobsonSobral Hey, sorry I'm seeing this a year later. I ended up taking the "categories" out of the channel:entries because it's like you said; it became hardcoded. My solution ended up being a simple "show="not XX|XX|XX," the XXs being the category IDs. And it also turns out all I had to do was delete the backslash in the {categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path='news/'}">{category_name}{/categories} to make it work...

Comment: So, please, fill the answer and mark t as right (even one year later). ;-)